# Error when opening project on Construct 2

Tags: html, construct-2

I'm getting this error when I open the project on Construct 2, How can i solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is indicating that the file within the project is no longer available to load. Therefore it must have been deleted or moved.

You will need to go to the games directory and place biru.png within the texture directory.

This should help with the error, once the project is opened you can then delete the object or try find where the original file is.

Comment: What is texture directory means?

Answer (score 0):

**You can fix this,**

1. Open the layouts folder.
2. Open each xml file and search for Keyword "biru.png"
3. Once you located that, remove this event where it exists.
4. Save the XML and close editor.
5. Go back and open the "New project.caproj"

**If the Porject extension isn't ".caproj"**

1. First make a backup copy of this project file.
2. Right click on project and name it as .zip file.
3. Unzip the file
4. Navigate into Layouts folder
5. Open each xml file and search for Keyword "biru.png"
6. Once you located that, remove this event where it exists.
7. Save the XML and close editor.
8. Go back and open the "New project.caproj"